# How to disable defaults commands on discord.js-Commando?

Tags: javascript, bots, discord

I want to disable all defaults commands that comes with Commando. Im trying to use this code but I keep getting this same error every time.

I've already tried other formats of this same code, none of them worked.

```
bot.registry.registerDefaultCommands({
help: false, 
prefix: false, 
ping: false,
_eval: false,
unknownCommand: true, 
commandState: true
})


throw new Error(`A command with the name/alias "${command.name}" is already registered.`);
                            ^

Error: A command with the name/alias "eval" is already registered.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled upon this post and saw that it hasn't gotten an answer yet. So I'll share an answer.

Remove:

```
bot.registry.registerDefaultCommands({
help: false, 
prefix: false, 
ping: false,
_eval: false,
unknownCommand: true, 
commandState: true
})
```

Removing this will remove all default commands and you are free to name commands after these. If you need anymore help, reply to this post.