# How do I disable specific commands in discord.js-commando

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, discord, discord.js, commando

So I have been searching for a while now but I cant find a way to disable the default commands for commando I looked at this article:[How to disable defaults commands on discord.js-Commando?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54430142/how-to-disable-defaults-commands-on-discord-js-commando). But it didn't work for me here is my [main.js](https://srcshare.io/?id=609d43f60b940fda48097ee2) code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this if you just want to remove the default commands but keep the default types and groups provided by commando.

```js
client.registry
    .registerGroups([
      ['administrator', 'administrator commands'],
      ['moderation', 'moderation commands'],
      ['members', 'member commands'],
      ['economy', 'economy'],
      ['misc', 'misc commands'],
    ])
    .registerDefaultTypes()
    .registerDefaultGroups()
    .registerDefaultCommands({
      help: false,
      prefix: false,
      ping: true,
      eval: true,
      unknownCommand: false,
      commandState: false,
    })
    .registerCommandsIn(path.join(__dirname, 'cmds'))
```

Comment: I want to keep some commands like ping and eval but remove others like help and unknown command response.

Comment: also I am getting a error when I try the code above this is the error:https://srcshare.io/?id=609ea3e30b940fb2aa097f49

Comment: ok i have edited the code snippet to accept other commands